# How to use/run .NET Framework dll/app from .NET Core WebAPI

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

Is there a way to run/use .NET Framework app/dll in .NET Core WebAPI? I am aware that .NET Core does not work with .NET Framework so I am asking about somekind of workaround.

I have tried .NET Framework Console App that I open from WebAPI but I am not sure if that is good idea. It does not work anytime, specialy when two users tries run it at the same time.

```cs
string path = hostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath + exePath;
string json = ConvertToBase64(object);

Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.FileName = path;
p.StartInfo.Arguments = json;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.Start();

string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

p.WaitForExit();

return output;
```

I do not want to use .NET Framework for my API. I do not want to use RabbitMQ and similar because it is require couple of components to install.
I need to use some methods from .NET Framework dlls in .NET Core WebAPI. I do not have access to .NET Framework dll code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In truth, it's not incompatible. .NET Core supports .NET Standard 2.0, which has a broad enough API footprint that most things in .NET Framework are supported as well. The main exclusions are obvious ones: Windows-specific APIs that obviously won't work cross-platform, which means they won't work in .NET Core.

As such, the answer to your question is another question: what exactly are the .NET Framework libraries doing? You can add a reference to the libraries from a .NET Core project, but you will get a warning telling you that they may not work correctly. It's on you to then determine if they do or do not work, and if everything is fine, you can suppress the warning.

If there are issues, then you can opt to target .NET Framework instead of .NET Core. You can still use ASP.NET Core while targeting .NET Framework; you simply will be tied to Windows, instead of able to deploy cross-platform. That may not even be an issue for you, though. Additionally, it may only be a temporary situation. .NET Core 3.0 should get you over any remaining humps, once it's released, so it's possible you can retarget your project to that later.

Comment: These libs are from ERP system (not mine). I'm trying to do a small web version of that. Since the SQL inserts are so complicated, I am forced to use their COM Objects to add documents, customers, products etc. Only adding new stuff I have to do this way, all data selecting is done by SQL.

Comment: The fact that you don't own them doesn't matter. The fact that you're using COM does. You'll have to target .NET Framework for your Core app, but it's totally doable. I have a Core API that communicates with a COM library myself.

Comment: So it is just that simple? I just have to add all the ERP references that I need and it should work? Honestly? Last time when I try that with .NET Core 2.1 I could not even build a project. I just assumed that it is impossible to make .NET Core API with .NET Framework dlls because Core is much different than Framework.

Comment: There's .NET Core and then there's ASP.NET Core. .NET Core complies with .NET Standard 2.0 and can therefore work with anything else that complies with .NET Standard 2.0. While that's not completely true of .NET Framework, the C# compiler makes a special exception and will at least *try*. However, if you use any non-.NET Standard APIs, then your app will crash. COM is one such API. However, ASP.NET Core can target .NET Framework just as well as .NET Core (you aren't restricted to .NET Core, just because you're using ASP.NET Core). If you target .NET Framework, you'll be fine.

Comment: Ok. Can you guide me what do I need to change in order to get this working?

Comment: Not sure exactly what you're looking for. You just need to change the target framework. Edit your project file and change it to `<TargetFramework>net48</TargetFramework>` or whatever version of .NET Framework you want to target.